# Using tableview for folder-system

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to load employees in a tableview.
The first time I load my tableview, I want to load all the employees having no supervisor, then, when I click on a cell (which contains a employee), I want to load all the supervisees of that certain employee.
I'm using a navigation controller, so I want to navigate back and forth. I'll need to push a new instance of my tableview over and over again, I guess. But the problem is, I'm initiating a new Employee object, also over and over again, but how do I manage this?
Cause I'll need to save the superviseex of the supervisorx to the supervisorx for example. 
I click on supervisorx, a new tableview loads, with no employees in it. I add a superviseex to this table, but this means my employee object is now superviseex. How can I manage that I can save superviseex to supervisorx, both Employee objects.

Answer (score 1):

try putting a flag on the employee stating that they are a supervisor. Then you can use that to distinguish them.

I would have another place that lets me see all non supervisors without a supervisor.

Also you make two relationships for employee to point to the employee entity One called supervisor which is a many to one relationship. and the inverse being employees which is a one to many relationship.

Now you will want 3 Controllers.

1. the main root controller for your app that shows your default table with default settings. (all employees where isSupervisor == YES)... Use NSFetchedResultController for the table
2. the Employees table controller. that takes in an Employee and creates an NSFetchedResultsController off the employee to show all the employees attached to said employee. The table should use that NSFetchedResultsController to display its employees.
3. the Employee info controller. showing the employee data and letting you link back to their supervisor (for employee info) or their employees (another copy of the Employee table controller)

navigation holds your controllers for you. so you can alloc, init (, autorelease if your non arc) and push.

if they stack up 100 items then they will be the one to deal with it.

If you want to clear the stack when they close the app you can set navigationController.viewControllers array manually in deactivate and activate of the app.

Aside from that. make the controllers handle their own data access. and when you save a context item you have two options.

option 1. Use one context (Important: Keep all data access on the same thread as the context. and if serial thread is used then @synchronized(managedObjectContext) is a must

option 2. implement the Save Notification of managedObjectContext to propagate your save throughout the rest of the object context's

**NOTE:** If you use multiple threads you can pass objects across thread with managedObjectContext.objectID at which point you can load from the `-[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID*)]` you can do this on any managed object id where `managedObjectID.isTemporaryID == NO`

Ray has a great article on how to use NSFetchedResultsController and even includes making the tables gracefully update when the FetchedResults have changed.

here is the link to the article [Core Data Tutorial How to Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but im still stuck with one concern. I have a property employee in detailview. In detailview i want to add a employee,  so i make a new instance of employee, but when i make a new instance, my app has lost the knowledge of the old employee instance   (the supervisor where i want to add the new employee to). Or do i need 2 properties of employee then? Or am i thinking wrong about the whole oo concept?

Comment: when you create an employee. you get that employee in a variable. its up to you where that variable gets put. employee can be supervisor, subordinate or just a temporary variable. You make the call where you want, but if you have a property named employee and you overwrite it. you will not have that original to work with. Just make another variable to work with for that purpose and the database will let you keep and work with them both. and a one to many relationship will be an NSSet* not an Employee* so you can put more than one in it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand but I'll try.

You're pushing new instances of view controllers, not views, so you can have a property in the controller that says what supervisor it's displaying data for.  If it has nil as the supervisor, it can retrieve all employees with no supervisor and if it's given a valid supervisor, it can display the employees that report to that supervisor.  With core data that's just reading the contents of a set (assuming a one-to-many relationship) rather than having to fetch anything.

Comment: thanks, so make a property for a supervisor and one for an employee?

Comment: If you have a relationship between a supervisor and reporting employees, you don't need a separate property for the employee.

Comment: this is where im stuck, how can i have 2 instances of an employee at the same time. I ne
ed one for saving a new employee and one for connecting with relationship, supervision, imo

Comment: You've convinced me that my first guess was correct; that is, I really don't understand your problem.  :-)